# Using Chutzpah where WebPack compiles ts to single js file

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, webpack, chutzpah

I've created a default ASP.NET Core Web Application (File -> New Project -> Visual C# -> .NET Core) with the Angular template.  This is a 100% out-of-the-box template in VS 2017 with .NET Core 2 with no changes by me.  It has one JS test file already in ClientApp/app/components/counter/counter.components.spec.ts, and I want to get Chutzpah working on this project.

I'm new to .NET Core and Webpack (but not Chutzpah or jasmine tests, though).  As far as I can tell, in this project webpack produces a bundled js file at ./wwwroot/dist/main-client.js from the typescript files, and it does this at runtime, not compile-time.  Honestly, I'm mystified as to what causes webpack to kick off at runtime.

It seems like almost all the common samples and questions about using Chutzpah involve a project where each .ts file has a corresponding .js compiled file in the same folder.  But this default project doesn't do that; it compiles the TS to JS at runtime and bundles all in one seamless operation.  I like that setup and really don't want to have to get away from that; it's very clean.

But for the life of me I cannot even *guess* as to how to write a chutzpah.json config file that will work in this situation.  **Where do I begin?**  I've looked at the [compilation samples from the chutzpah project](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/tree/master/Samples/Compilation) and there are so many differences between this default config and what the samples are doing that I don't know how to move forward.

For reference, the contents of the test file component.spec.ts are below.

```
/// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
import { assert } from 'chai';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter.component';
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';

let fixture: ComponentFixture<CounterComponent>;

describe('Counter component', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({ declarations: [CounterComponent] });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CounterComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should display a title', async(() => {
        const titleText = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('h1').textContent;
        expect(titleText).toEqual('Counter');
    }));

    it('should start with count 0, then increments by 1 when clicked', async(() => {
        const countElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('strong');
        expect(countElement.textContent).toEqual('0');

        const incrementButton = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
        incrementButton.click();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(countElement.textContent).toEqual('1');
    }));
});
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @alekkowalczyk Frustratingly, no.  I sort of moved on but have not stopped wishing for a solution.  The latest Angular templates in Visual Studio, though, don't compile .ts to .js at all at compile-time; the compilation happens by Angular more or less at runtime, so that makes things really interesting.